# How to trigger a delayed function call after you have navigated away from the page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So I have a really ask but the implementation is eluding me.
I want to simulate the completion of a task in the background in our product demo.

The User Journey :

1. Arrive at the home page
2. Click button on the home page -> Button goes into loading state (button replaced by loading animation)
3. We continue on with the demo and navigate away
4. We want to come back to the home page after "execution complete" .

Well how do we know if execution is complete ? Well that's where this delayed alert I'm trying to implement comes in. I'd like an alert to be sent out , regardless of what page I am on in the app after some x minutes/seconds of clicking that button.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this ?
I am trying with redux-toolkit but so far it's only working on the page itself and
if I return to the page after navigating away.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways,

1. elevate the state to the point which covers both home page and all the navigation pages, Use react context API to pass data and use useEffect hook to track task completion and do the need full.
2. Use native javascript to trigger custom event and add an event listner to it [Read more about curtom events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Although this is all just theory, I can help more after viewing the code.